# Hikari Datasource Open Connection more than maximum pool size limit

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

x and hikari datasource for my jpa queries (version 3.4.5).My problem is I set my datasource  maximum pool size property.Even though I set maximum pool size,I see more connection than my maximum poolsize at oracle.At this time when I checked my spring logs I seems connection limit is equal my maximumconnection pool size
Is it possible to hikari datasource can open more connection than my maximum poolsize limit?

In my code side I set maximum connection like that

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
 dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(5)

My Oracle Query(I see 7 connections at oracle)
Select * from v$session where where username='xxxxx'

My spring Log(I see 5 connections)
[HikariPool-3 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-3 - Pool stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, if [HikariPool connectionBag](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L93) [waitingThreadCounts](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/util/ConcurrentBag.java#L325) more or equal then maximum pool size.

But in your stacktrace waiting size is 0 and the total is 5 (total value is all connections from [connectionBag](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L366)). So you have a connection in other places.

Comment: As I understand my problem not maximul pool size,somehow I see more than one hikari pool created HikariPool-1,HikariPool-2 but I dont understand root cause,how can hikari datasource create more than one pool